# Firebase storage | how to update customMetaData with merge true

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

When uploading a file.. I have set the following custom meta data

```
const metadata = {
  customMetadata: {
    user: userId,
    disabled: 'false'
  },
};
```

and upload it like

```
uploadBytes(ref(this.str, invoicePath), invoiceFile, metadata),
```

Now some time later I would like to set disabled to true. Doing smth like this

```
const metadata = {
  customMetadata: {
    disabled: 'true',
  },
};
updateMetadata(ref(this.str, invoicePath), metadata)
```

**will remove the `user key` in the customMetaData**

Is it possible to update it without setting the `user key` again??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the metadata you pass always completely replaces the existing metadata for that object. If you want to retain values from the previous metadata, you will have to perform a read-modify-write sequence.

---

**Update**: Interestingly enough the documentation on [updating metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#update_file_metadata) says:

> You can update file metadata at any time after the file upload completes by using the `updateMetadata()` method. Refer to the full list for more information on what properties can be updated. **Only the properties specified in the metadata are updated, all others are left unmodified.** `updateMetadata()` returns a `Promise` containing the complete metadata, or an error if the `Promise` rejects.